# I get Linker Errors for the following code. Is this Circular dependency or am I messing up any Includes

Tags: c++, linker-errors, circular-dependency

[BinaryTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8wQD.png)

[Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0J9r.png)

and my main is

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class Node;

//#include"Node.h"
#include"BinaryTree.h"


int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> bt; 
    //bt.Insert(20);

    return 0;
}
```

So I have two .h files BinaryTree and Node and their respective .cpp files. I am using making a class variable of type Node in BinaryTree and I have declared BinaryTree and friend class in Node. When i run the program i get the following Linker errors -

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BinaryTree::BinaryTree(void)" (??0?$BinaryTree@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main Practice    C:\Users\u1017574\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Practice\Practice\main.obj  1

Comment: please post complete code

Comment: I have put links for both the files above